# how to modify value in ngif template?

Tags: angular, ng-template

i am new to Angular. and i want to modify value in ngif template.
i generate component named research-list, and i want to view the research which define in research-list.ts,
but when i use modify() in research-list.component.html, and define modify() in research-list.component.ts, it didn't work. how can i fix them??

thank you!

<research-list.component.html>

```
<div class="section">

    <div class="header">
        <div class="label">
           {{currentYear}}
        </div>
    </div>

    <table>
        <div *ngFor = "let re of research">
            <div *ngIf = "re.year==currentYear; then ifCase else modify()"></div>
                
                <ng-template #ifCase>
                    <tr>
                        <div class="content" fxLayout="row wrap" fxLayout.xs="column" fxLayoutGap="100px">
                    
                            <div class="research">
                                <span class="title">
                                    {{re.title}}
                                </span>
                                <span class="obliqueDesc">
                                    {{re.obliqueDesc}}
                                </span>
                                <div class="members">
                                    {{re.members}}
                                </div>
                            </div>
            
                            <div class="picture" fxFlex="50" fxFlex.xs="100">
            
                                <div class="image">
                                    <img src="{{re.image}}" alt="{{re.title}}">
                                </div>
                            </div>
            
                        </div>
            
                    </tr>
                </ng-template>
                
        </div>
    </table>
    
</div>
```

<research-list.component.ts>

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Research } from './research';
import { ResearchList } from './research-list';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-research-list',
  templateUrl: './research-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./research-list.component.scss']
})


export class ResearchListComponent implements OnInit {

  research : Research[] = ResearchList;
  currentYear = 2021;

  modify()
  {
    return this.currentYear = this.currentYear-1;
  }

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {

  }

}
```

<research-list.ts>

```
import { Research } from "./research";

export const ResearchList : Research[] = [
    
 { year : 2021, title : 'VISLAB', obliqueDesc : 'Developing VISLAB Website. Using Angular, Node.js, express, PostgreSQL.', members : 'Ji Hwan Kim and Jung Min Lee / 2021.6 ~', image : 'assets/images/main_banner_0.jpg'},
 { year : 2021, title : 'CareNet', obliqueDesc : 'A project to analyze and visualize the power data of Korea Electric Power Corporation (KEPCO)', members : 'Sang Jun Park and San Hong / 2021.6 ~', image : 'assets/images/CareNet_main.jpg'},
 { year : 2021, title : 'PatientFlow', obliqueDesc : 'A project that analyzes and visualizes hospital-related data across the country and clusters it', members : 'Jung Yeon Kim and Jin Woo Park / 2021.6 ~', image : 'assets/images/PatientFlow_main.png'},
 { year : 2020, title : 'PatientFlow', obliqueDesc : 'A project that analyzes and visualizes hospital-related data across the country and clusters it', members : 'Jung Yeon Kim and Jin Woo Park / 2021.6 ~', image : 'assets/images/PatientFlow_main.png'},
 { year : 2020, title : 'PatientFlow', obliqueDesc : 'A project that analyzes and visualizes hospital-related data across the country and clusters it', members : 'Jung Yeon Kim and Jin Woo Park / 2021.6 ~', image : 'assets/images/PatientFlow_main.png'},
 { year : 2019, title : 'PatientFlow', obliqueDesc : 'A project that analyzes and visualizes hospital-related data across the country and clusters it', members : 'Jung Yeon Kim and Jin Woo Park / 2021.6 ~', image : 'assets/images/PatientFlow_main.png'},
 { year : 2019, title : 'PatientFlow', obliqueDesc : 'A project that analyzes and visualizes hospital-related data across the country and clusters it', members : 'Jung Yeon Kim and Jin Woo Park / 2021.6 ~', image : 'assets/images/PatientFlow_main.png'},
 { year : 2019, title : 'PatientFlow', obliqueDesc : 'A project that analyzes and visualizes hospital-related data across the country and clusters it', members : 'Jung Yeon Kim and Jin Woo Park / 2021.6 ~', image : 'assets/images/PatientFlow_main.png'},
 { year : 2019, title : 'PatientFlow', obliqueDesc : 'A project that analyzes and visualizes hospital-related data across the country and clusters it', members : 'Jung Yeon Kim and Jin Woo Park / 2021.6 ~', image : 'assets/images/PatientFlow_main.png'},
 { year : 2018, title : 'PatientFlow', obliqueDesc : 'A project that analyzes and visualizes hospital-related data across the country and clusters it', members : 'Jung Yeon Kim and Jin Woo Park / 2021.6 ~', image : 'assets/images/PatientFlow_main.png'},

];
```

<research.ts>

```
export class Research
{
    year : number;
    title : string;
    obliqueDesc : string;
    members : string;
    image : string;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

'else' part in *ngIf takes a template variable reference. It won't work like normal if else.
Try keeping the logical part in .ts file and conditionally put elements in .html part

Answer (score 0):

## I have updated your mockup structure.

**Descriptions:** at first updated `re.year==currentYear` to `re.year===currentYear` there used Strict equality [learn more](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Strict_equality). and 2nd part condition, the condition not showed anyone in [Angular official doc](https://angular.io/api/common/NgIf) for about conditional templating. you can also learn more visite this link: https://angular.io/api/common/NgIf

```
<div class="section">

    <div class="header">
        <div class="label">
           {{currentYear}}
        </div>
    </div>

    <table>
        <div *ngFor = "let re of research">
            <div *ngIf = "re.year===currentYear; then ifCase else modifyTemplate"></div>
                
                <ng-template #ifCase>
                    <tr>
                        <div class="content" fxLayout="row wrap" fxLayout.xs="column" fxLayoutGap="100px">
                    
                            <div class="research">
                                <span class="title">
                                    {{re.title}}
                                </span>
                                <span class="obliqueDesc">
                                    {{re.obliqueDesc}}
                                </span>
                                <div class="members">
                                    {{re.members}}
                                </div>
                            </div>
            
                            <div class="picture" fxFlex="50" fxFlex.xs="100">
            
                                <div class="image">
                                    <img src="{{re.image}}" alt="{{re.title}}">
                                </div>
                            </div>
            
                        </div>
            
                    </tr>
                </ng-template>
                <ng-template #modifyTemplate>
                  this is another else component 'modifyed Template' 
                </ng-template>
                
        </div>
    </table>
    
</div>
```

**Thanks**

Comment: thank you, i have a additional question, can you answer about it? 
you said "this is another else component 'modifyed Template' ", so i made a another component called 'modify-current-year'. but i dont know how to bring currentYear variable in research-list.components.ts to modify-current-year.ts .. 
i write the sentence
"import { ResearchListComponent } from '../research-list/research-list.component';"
 in modify-current-year.ts file, and access by ResearchListComponent.currentYear, but it doesn't work. do i need to know the concept of "subscribe/rxjs/observable...etc"?? .

Comment: @shinbian11 use this way, <modify-current-year #modifyTemplate></modify-current-year>

Comment: you mean that 
<ng-template #modifyTemplate>
         <app-modify-current-year #modifyTemplate></app-modify-current-year>
 </ng-template>
like this?? and how can i use currentYear  at modify-current-year.ts file?

Answer (score 0):

I think you mistook how to use `ngIfThen`

```html
<div *ngIf = "re.year==currentYear; then ifCase else modify()"></div>
```

as here in `then` clause `ifCase` is a template, `else` should  also be a template variable only.

what you want to achieve can be easily achieved using a [pipe](https://angular.io/api/core/Pipe).